# I am having trouble with my advisor. Can someone help?

Tags: phd, graduate-school, advisor, interpersonal-issues, health

I am a 4th year Ph.D. student from India. I don't get any help from my advisor. He has always been demotivating me. In my entire 4 years, I have never got any moral support from him. I don't get any work-related him too. I am on my own.

AT the end of the 1st year, he told us he will not help us, he won't give us any recommendations, he wants a minimum of 4 journal from each of all and said we can leave if we want. But none of us could, since we knew, if we did, he will create a problem for us.

Infact, now situations have turned really bad. He calls me up asking me to write a small review of my 4th work. I send it to him. After 2 days he again calls me up saying he did not ask for it. Since he communicates visa phone, I have no way to prove he is being dishonest. Thinking he may have forgotten, I tried to remind him to which he asked me not to argue with him.

My paper recently got rejected. He calls me up to say that he has given me independence regarding work. On my first year, he called his students into his office and told them that he will not help with their work, will not give any recommendation, and he will not interfere in our work dynamics. We were on our own from the beginning, yet now he changed this situation into such as if he gave us the liberty to work alone, which in the real scenarios is basically the fact that he is incapable of giving any contribution to anyone's work. The worst part is he talks to all his students without respect, calling them at odd hours, telling them they are not working. But no one is ready to say anything to him since their PhDs depend on him and we know if we revolt, he won't give us our PhDs even if we have worked hard.

I am going through a lot of depression right now. There is no provision to complain to a higher authority regarding his behavior. One girl tried to complain to the HOD, she was denied PhD from my institution and her phd had to be obtained from another university with extra 3 years (6+3=9 years).  Please tell me if there is any way to solve this problem other than leaving Ph.D. under him and starting fresh under someone else? Or should I just keep working for my papers suffering in silence? My question is, to what limit should I tolerate?

Comment: "There is no provision to complain to a higher authority regarding his behavior" Are you sure about that?

Comment: @Eppicurtyes sir, one person tried to complain, she was denied her PhD

Comment: There are many questions of this kind on this forum, and many answers already given. Have you looked through them?

Comment: PhD is hard and your advisor is far from being fair and nice. What's your actual question? We don't know your department, the situation there, and means available. Voting to close as too broad.

Comment: You could try and fight on the grounds of consumer rights (http://www.consumerrights.org.in/rights.htm), but it sounds like for you personally it would probably be better to find another university to move to, sooner rather than later.

Comment: You are not getting an education if your supervisor is not involved.  Time to leave.  Why waste your youth?

Comment: Life is more important than a PhD. Leave this nasty environment.